# How to load an electron apps from a URL

Tags: electron

When running electron with an invalid option, I get:

```
A path to an Electron app may be specified. It must be one of the following:
  - index.js file.
  - Folder containing a package.json file.
  - Folder containing an index.js file.
  - .html/.htm file.
  - http://, https://, or file:// URL.
```

If I try to load from the filesystem, with "`electron .`" it loads my apps, but if I serve that same directory with nginx or node serve and try to run electron against it with "`electron http://localhost:3000/`" it loads a blank screen, or if I add a filename to the path, literally the content of that file.

Is it possible to load an apps from a URL in electron? How?

Answer (score -2):

Electron cannot run "electron apps" from a URL.

> when we load a remote URL (in this case an http:// url) we disable nodeIntegration as per our [Security Guidelines](https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/security#2-disable-nodejs-integration-for-remote-content).

https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/security#2-disable-nodejs-integration-for-remote-content

https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/17609